# Comparing geometry between layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I'm using QGIS 3.2.3.  I have:

1. a shapefile layer of town outlines (about 600 features)
2. a spatialite layer of points (about 20000 features)

I would like to filter the points layer to show only those points that are east of a town in the shapefile layer.

I'm stymied by the lack of an obvious join condition between the two sets of data and the fact that one data source is a spatialite database and one is not.

Conceptually, I want something like:

```
select *
from
  pointtable
  join polytable on (???)
where
  polytable.town = 'SomeTown'
  and st_x(polytable.geom) > st_x(pointtable.geom)
```

...but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Is there a `townID` or similar on the point layer? else you will need to refine how you associate a point to a given town (ex: points just West of new York are East of Los Angeles; another point can be East of town X..., but 1 000 km up north)

Comment: The points are limited to Massachusetts, so I really only care about the easy/west relationship.  Nothing is "too far" north or south.  The points don't have a town id. I can arrange for them to have a town name which should match in most cases.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Can I join *layers* on an expression, rather than a column name?  The join condition would be something like `on lower(towns.town) = lower(points.city)`, since there is inconsistent casing in the two data sets. I guess the alternative is to filter the data first, rather than using the source data verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a virtual layer (`layer -> add layer -> virtual layer`). Set both your layers as base for the new layer, and enter a valid SQL-code, this should yield the desired result.